# `.select_by_visible_text()` is failed to select element?

Tags: python, select, selenium

I'm not sure why `.select_by_visible_text()` is failed to select element?

take this website as example:https://www-01.ibm.com/products/hardware/configurator/americas/bhui/launchNI.wss

```
driver.get("https://www-01.ibm.com/products/hardware/configurator/americas/bhui/launchNI.wss")
driver.find_element_by_id("modelnumber").send_keys('7383AC1')
driver.find_element_by_name("submit").click()
FC='A1G7'
option_el=find_element_by_xpath("//option[contains(text(),'%s')]" %FC)
select_el=option_el.find_element_by_xpath("..")
Select(select_el).select_by_visible_text(FC)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
driver.get("https://www-01.ibm.com/products/hardware/configurator/americas/bhui/launchNI.wss")
driver.find_element_by_id("modelnumber").send_keys('7383AC1')
driver.find_element_by_name("submit").click()
FC='A1G7'
option_el=find_element_by_xpath("//option[contains(text(),'%s')]" %FC)
option_el.click()

take click() instead of select
```

Answer (score 2):

`Select.select_by_visible_text()` requires *the full text* of the option desired, not just a piece of it. that's why Stella's solution works and yours does not, but it's also more efficient.

Comment: just now noticed that Stella is both the asker and answerer... duh :^]